# Slight damage to LGA 1151 - Is it fatal/fixable?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, processor-socket

Below is a picture of my LGA 1151 socket on a motherboard. 2 pins seem to be damaged, circled in red.

I assume it won't work in this condition?
Is it worth trying to nudge the pins back into alignment or is this fatal?

Any assistance gratefully received.

[image: Damaged LGA 1151]

Answer (score 0):

You can unbend the bent pins carefully.
Just watch one of several YouTube videos or google it to show many links on how to
unbend pins.
It is only serious if you have a broken pin, and then the only thing that you can do
is install it and see if the CPU works correctly.

Many pins are redundant (like ground pins as an example).
If it works correctly even when you stress test it, then you can continue to use it.

So just unbend the pins very carefully, using a magnifying glass if required.
Trying it out is not supposed to break anything, but don't use force when putting
the CPU in.

If you are unsure of yourself, take the computer to be repaired.

Comment: idk why this got a downvote. You can either try to straighten the pins or throw it away. I've done it before on a mobo when I noobed & dropped a CPU onto the pins. It's fiddly & you've got to be careful; it may or may not work, but what's to lose at this stage?